# What metadata can actually go into a scrapy.Field object?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was reviewing the [docs for Items](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html?highlight=field#declaring-fields) in Scrapy today, and came across the followoing line:

> Field objects are used to specify metadata for each field...You can
> specify any kind of metadata for each field. There is no restriction
> on the values accepted by Field objects.

Within the docs however, it seems like the only kind of "metadata" passed to the Field objects are functions (in this example a serializer) or input/output processors.

So I went into Python and tried to make the following Item:

```
class ScrapyPracticeItem(scrapy.Item):
     name = scrapy.Field()
     age = scrapy.Field('color':'purple')
```

But this was not accepted syntax either.

I am confused now -- could anyone give me a better definition of what they mean by metadata? Do they only mean transformations of the data in the item? Could it contain more information?

Comment: what is it you are trying to do by adding the `(color: purple )` to the field?

Comment: I was trying to understand the limits of what exactly they meant by metadata -- there was no specific reason for adding this exact attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field object is simply an alias for the standard python dictionary.  This is the actual description in the scrapy API

> class scrapy.Field([arg])¶
>
> > The Field class is just an alias to the built-in dict class and doesn’t provide any extra functionality or attributes. In other words, Field objects are plain-old Python dicts. A separate class is used to support the item declaration syntax based on class attributes.

So anything that can be used as a dictionary value can be assigned to a scrapy field already without using any parameters in its constructor. The following example shows how you can create a color

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    color = scrapy.Field()
    age = scrapy.Field()
```

When they say you can set the metadata, the field is the metadata for the item that you are setting. the option to add a serializer isn't actually directly handled by the Field, instead it is handled by the Item object or its MetaClass.

This is the actual source code for the scrapy.Field class:

```
class Field(dict):
    """Container of field metadata"""

# that is it
```

All data processing and name assignment is taken care of by one of `scrapy`'s custom metaclasses.

Scrapy is intentionally structured and borrows a lot of its methodology from `django` framework. The Item class and it's associated metaclass are designed to work similar to `django`s `Model` class which it uses for communicating with a storage backend, usually a database.

However because scrapy items can be extracted and used in innumerable ways the `Item` class allows much more flexibility than its `django` counterpart, so there really are no limitations on what can be considered metadata or what can be stored in an `Item` class.

Comment: OH. So if I understand you correctly, the field objects are the metadata it's referencing in that sentence? In other words, I misread the sentence and assumed what you put into the Field objects are the metadata, not the Field objects themselves?

Comment: Also reading more they say "there is no reference list of all available metadata keys...the main goal of Field objects is to provide a way to define all field metadata in one place." What do they mean by metadata? When I think of metadata I think of attributes of the data. Here it seems like they mean something closer to the ways one transforms the data (i.e. serializer)

Comment: Ahhhhh ok that makes a ton of sense actually (I have a passing familiarity with Django). Per the Django docs, "model metadata is “anything that’s not a field”, such as ordering options, database table names, or human-readable singular and plural names". I take it that's actually what they mean by metadata here?

Comment: @waterboy  yes and more... like i said scrapy allows much more flexibility so metadata can literally be whatever you want it to be and represent anything you want to represent and be interpreted or serialized in whatever way you want because in the end its just a dictionary that is dressed up a little and has a few extra features

Comment: Could you give me an example of what "and more" could look like? I can't find an example anywhere online beyond the serializer example in the docs.

Comment: @waterboy  When I say more i mean there are more possibilities because you are not limited to controlling how data is stored in a database.  When it comes to built in functionality, then the serailizer is pretty much the only option that i know of...  I don't even use that though because I typically handle data processing in the pipelines